# How to find an element by image

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, groovy

As we know [selenium](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/locators/) supports multiple locators strategy to find an element on web page.

But my requirement is different, I have some sites where any locators supported by selenium is not enough to find an element uniquely.

As selenium gives facility to create own custom locator strategy to find an element, I am trying to create **image** locator which could be able to find an element using **base64** `String` of a sub image as [appium](http://appium.io/docs/en/advanced-concepts/image-elements/) do.

**Points for image locator:**

1. Launch browser with URL
2. Capture screenshot of the page
3. Detect **x**,**y** location of the sub image from screenshot
4. Find element using **x**, **y** location from the page

To achieve this task I am creating custom `Image` locator as below :

```
public class ByImage extends By {

    String imageBase64String

    /**
     * @param imageBase64String
     */
    public ByImage(String imageBase64String) {
        this.imageBase64String = imageBase64String
    }

    @Override
    public List<WebElement> findElement(SearchContext context) {
        List<WebElement> els = findElements(context)
        if (els) {
            return els.get(0)
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Element not found")
    }

    @Override
    public List<WebElement> findElements(SearchContext context) {
       //Get current screenshot
        byte[] screenshotByte = ((TakesScreenshot)context).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES))
        byte[] subImgToFindByte = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(imageBase64String)
        //Convert buffred image to get height and width of subimage
        BufferedImage bufferedSubImgToFind = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(subImgToFindByte ));

        //Here I need a mechanism to get coordinates of sub image from screenshot
        //Suppose I able to find x, y
        double x
        double y

        //Now find element using coordinates
        //Now calculate center point
        int centerX = int(x + (bufferedSubImgToFind.getWidth() / 2))
        int centerY = int(y + (bufferedSubImgToFind.getHeight() / 2))

        JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)context)

        return js.executeScript("return document.elementsFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1]);", centerX, centerY)
      }   
  }
```

Now the test case is as :

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()
driver.get("<URL>")
WebElement elementByImage = driver.findElement(new ByImage("<Base64 String of the subimage>"))
```

I'm able to achieve everything except a better library to detect exact coordinates of `subimage` from an `image` to find an element using coordinates.

Could anyone suggest me a better approach to achieve this task?

Comment: There's no information in the image name that you can find in the `src` of the image tag or something similar? Please post some same HTML so we can see. Do you know the size of the image or anything about it? If you can find it in a larger screenshot of the page, you must know some details about it. What do you know?

Comment: @JeffC I'm just trying to create a custom locator which would be able to find an element using image base64 string, in this case we just need to capture a particular element screenshot using any tools and convert it into base64 string and pass it into this custom locator, where in this custom locator it takes screenshot of while current visible page and trying to find that subimage from screenshot using some library like as `OpenCV`.

Comment: Now the size will matter if user will take screenshot from big screen and trying to find it on small screen, in that case we can simply `scale` the subimage with the current screenshot of the page so that we can easily get the correct coordinates. This is a generic solution I'm trying to achieve which is based on image that's why we don't need any `HTML` here.. Thanks.. :)

Comment: @JeffC For better understanding have a look here https://appiumpro.com/editions/32. this is appium tutorial where exactly appium is doing that which I want in web

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As @Dmitri suggested I'm going with [Java Bindings for OpenCV](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

[download appropriate OpenCV](https://opencv.org/releases/) and extract it into `classpath` and try to get coordinates as :

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Core.MinMaxLocResult;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

byte[] screenshotByte = ((TakesScreenshot)context).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES))
byte[] subImgToFindByte = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(imageBase64String)

System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
Mat source = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(screenshotByte), Imgcodecs.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
Mat template = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(subImgToFindByte), Imgcodecs.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

int result_cols = source.cols() - template.cols() + 1;
int result_rows = source.rows() - template.rows() + 1;
Mat outputImage = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

// Template matching method
Imgproc.matchTemplate(source, template, outputImage, Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED);

MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(outputImage);
// Now get the point
Point point = mmr.minLoc;
double x = point.x;
double y = point.y;

//Now get the find the element using x, y after calculating center point.
int centerX = int(x + (bufferedSubImgToFind.getWidth() / 2));
int centerY = int(y + (bufferedSubImgToFind.getHeight() / 2));

WebElement el = js.executeScript("return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1]);", centerX, centerY);
```

Hope It helps to everyone.

Answer (score 3):

There are different options you can go for, like:

1. You can use [Java Bindings for OpenCV](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in order to look up the subimage in the main screenshot, check out [Template Matching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/da9/tutorial_template_matching.html) article for comprehensive explanation and code snippets.
2. [Project Sikuli](http://doc.sikuli.org/) provides some simple APIs for image recognition/interaction
3. [SeeTest Automation](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TDB/SeeTestAutomation-+Image+Recognition+Properties) provides image recognition and [Object Repository](https://www.guru99.com/object-repository-selenium.html) pattern implementation for image templates